# iOS How to use system password to run a script?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, shell

I am creating a macOS app (using SwiftUI), it will run a script. To run a script I need the system (or admin) password. because when I run that script in Terminal it asked the user password and than run the script.
I am able to run the script on button click with a securefeild, but
It's not the appropriate to show user a securefeild and ask his system password in the app, while its against the apple guide line. So I removed that feild.
Now I dont have any idea how to run script after System password authentication.
To show user authentication I am using this.

```
    let context = LAContext()

    func authorize() {
        var error: NSError? = nil // Create optional error variable
        let reason = "This action requires your authentication for security purposes."

        let policy: LAPolicy = .deviceOwnerAuthentication // Adjust policy based on device capabilities (e.g., biometrics, passcode)
        context.evaluatePolicy(policy, localizedReason: reason, reply: { (success, error) in
            if success {
                // User was successfully authenticated
                **// Proceed with your script execution here, but the problem is I dont have user password here, and not found even from the Keychain, because before fetch password from keychain it should be store there**
                print("Success")
            } else {
                // Authentication failed or was canceled
                if let error = error {
                    // Handle the error appropriately
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        })
}
```

I think, I should save the password in keychain for security and than access but, first I need to get the password without breaking the apple guide lines.

Thats the whole problem, I did not found related this thing.

**Edited:**

When I run my script in the success case, it shows the message in the Xcode below terminal.

```
sudo: a password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem by myself. In my case `let context = LAContext()` is not working and no need for that.

To run script with Admin *no need to store password in keychain.* When writing script at that time write script with this thing.

```
let osacScript = "osascript -e 'do shell script \"\(script)\" with administrator privileges'"
```

We can write `sudo` script (sudo script needs when we want to perform some actions like create folder or move folder) like this

```
let osacScript = "osascript -e 'do shell script \"sudo \(script)\" with administrator privileges'"
```

The code solved my problem is below:

```
func installScript(scriptPath: String, installingDir: String) {
    let script = "\(scriptPath) --noprompt --dir \(installingDir) --key ABCKEY --region name-for-region --server https://myserver.com"
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { // I am using SwiftUI so to avoid blocking the UI running script in the background.
        let osacScript = "osascript -e 'do shell script \"\(script)\" with administrator privileges'"
        print(osacScript)
        var arguments = [String]()
        arguments.append("-c")
        arguments .append(osacScript)
        let process = Process()
        process.launchPath = "/bin/bash" // Specify the shell to use
        process.arguments = arguments
        
        let pipe = Pipe()
        process.standardOutput = pipe
        process.standardError = pipe // Redirect standard error to the same pipe

        let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        process.launch()
        process.waitUntilExit()
        let data = fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let logFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "logfile", ofType: "txt")! // This thing can lead to error if file does not exist, so make sure it should be optional.
        if let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("output:\(output)")
            // Write output to file
            do {
                try output.write(toFile: logFilePath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            } catch {
                print("Error writing to file: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```